# JQuery .replaceWith() or .html()

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change one div content to another and vice versa when the button is clicked. I would also like to add some animation in between for the separate divs in the content area. I would like for it to switch between both divs. for intsance, showing products for section1 when pressing btn1 and then products for section2 when pressing btn2.

HTML

```
<button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn">btn2</button>

<div id="section1"> 
<!-- content goes here -->
</div>
<div id="section2">
<!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var section1 = $('#section1')
  var section2 = $('#section2')

  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('#section1').html($('#section2').html());
  });

  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    $('#section2').html($('#section1').html());
  });
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off using `show()` and `hide()`:

```
$('#btn1').click(function() {
   $('#section1').show();
   $('#section2').hide();
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
   $('#section2').show();
   $('#section1').hide();
});
```

It's easier than messing with the HTML.  Also, when you get more advanced at it, you can experiment with various effects, such as fading.  [Here](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)'s a demo of various jQuery effects that you can use with showing and hiding (there are other effects as well, that don't involve showing and hiding).  (This demo requires jQuery-UI to be installed as well.)

Comment: Awesome! This works. Thank you! I tried this earlier but couldn't seem to make it work. How would you implement the fade in? I was thinking about making other divs within that div fade in one a time.

Comment: I'd also mention it's better for performance reasons and registered DOM events.  An element that is hidden and then shown can will keep it's DOM events (click, mouseup etc).

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/fade-effect/).  It can be as simple as `$('#section1').show('fade');`.

Comment: @BobRodes this is a fantastic answer, I'm always impressed by answers that find the root need and answer that instead of the surface question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I totally agree. Any material you guys would recommend me looking at?

Comment: @BobRodes Thank you sir!

Comment: Try `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()`

Comment: You can also use as @KingRider gives, which are equivalent shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks Erik.  It helps that @ColeGauthier did a good job of explaining what he wanted to do.

Comment: @BobRodes Not a problem! I used this 

$('#section1').hide();
$('#section2').fadeIn(1000).show();

Comment: @ColeGauthier I'm sorry, I just realized that my `$('#section1').show('fade')` is jQuery-UI, not just plain jQuery.  Yours is the correct way to do it in jQuery.  I like to use the other way because you can add in a number of other effects (`.show('blind')` for example) as in the demo I linked.

Comment: @BobRodes That would make a whole lot of sense why it wasn't working the correct way. Thank you for pointing me in right direction!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll have to be more careful to check which is which in future.  I tend to think of jQuery UI as all the widget stuff, not enhanced effects as well.

Comment: @BobRodes Guess so, but it's still in the right direction. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look a like replace fun lol

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button#btn1').bind('click', function() {
    temp = $('div#section1').text();
    $('div#section1').text($('div#section2').text());
    $('div#section2').text(temp);
  });
  $('button#btn2').bind('click', function() {
    temp = $('div#section2').text();
    $('div#section2').text($('div#section1').text());
    $('div#section1').text(temp);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><button id="btn1" type="button" class="btn">btn1</button></p>
<p><button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn">btn2</button></p>
<p><hr></p>
<p><div id="section1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div></p>
<p><div id="section2">Lorem consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas in.</div></p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the above accepted code works wonderfully!

Comment: @ColeGauthier it´s ok